# SQLite Exception: no such table found

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

First of all do not mark this question as duplicate. I searched for every possible options and tried them but it still isn't working. Changed the database version, Cleared the data and reinstalled the app as well. I've the database placed correctly in the database folder. Still no such table found while compiling error. Help me figure out what I'm lacking in this code or what I'm doing wrong.

[image: database folder]

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {


    String DB_PATH = null;
    private static String DB_NAME = "externaldatabase";
    private SQLiteDatabase myDataBase;
    private final Context myContext;
    Cursor c =null;

    public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DB_NAME, null, 11);
        this.myContext = context;
        this.DB_PATH = "/data/data/" + context.getPackageName() + "/" + "databases/";
        Log.e("Path 1", DB_PATH);
    }

    public void createDataBase() throws IOException {
        boolean dbExist = checkDataBase();
        if (dbExist) {
        } else {
            this.getReadableDatabase();
            try {
                copyDataBase();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.toString();
            }
        }
    }

    private boolean checkDataBase() {
        SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;
        try {
            String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
            checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
        } catch (SQLiteException e) {
        }
        if (checkDB != null) {
            checkDB.close();
        }
        return checkDB != null ? true : false;
    }

    private void copyDataBase() throws IOException {
        InputStream myInput = myContext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);
        String outFileName = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
        OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[10];
        int length;
        while ((length = myInput.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }
        myOutput.flush();
        myOutput.close();
        myInput.close();

    }

    public void openDataBase() throws SQLException {
        String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
        myDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);

    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void close() {
        if (myDataBase != null)
            myDataBase.close();
        super.close();
    }


    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        if (newVersion > oldVersion)
            try {
                copyDataBase();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();

            }
    }



    public Cursor query(String table, String[] columns, String selection, String[] selectionArgs, String groupBy, String having, String orderBy) {
        return myDataBase.query("rates_table", null, null, null, null, null, null);
    }


    public String getFare(String name, String depart){

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();


        String [] columns = {"rate"};

        c = db.rawQuery("select rate from rates_table where place1 = '"+name+"'and place3 = '"+depart+"' or place1 = '"+depart+"'and place3 = '"+name+"'", new String[]{});


        StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
        while(c.moveToNext()){

            String employyename = c.getString(0);


            buffer.append(employyename+"");
        }

        return buffer.toString();

    } }
```

Comment: Where you have created table

Comment: @Anil as you can see the database is external

Comment: Have you tried running it on simulator and going to the app folder and see if your DB is copied correctly and contains the table in it?

Comment: Have you tried check your table in your database to open in other sqlite db browser or any other external db browser??

Comment: Your class has a lot of problems. Make life easier for yourself by using [android-sqlite-asset-helper](https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper).

Comment: **1** - This `String [] columns = {"rate"};` is **useless**. **2** - `c = db.rawQuery("select rate from rates_table where place1 = '"+name+"'and place3 = '"+depart+"' or place1 = '"+depart+"'and place3 = '"+name+"'", new String[]{});` replace `new String[]{}):` with `null);`, since you are not using parameters. **3** - No need to waste CPU time by appending an **empty string** to a string: `buffer.append(employyename+"");`. It should be `buffer.append(employyename);`. **4** - Make sure your table name in the db is actually **rates_table**.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have any code in `onCreate()` method. Call your `createDatabase()` method inside `onCreate()`.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    createDataBase();
}
```

- Use [AssetManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/AssetManager.html) to read file from asset folder
- Use [Stetho](http://facebook.github.io/stetho/) to check if the database is actually created.

Answer (score 0):

You did not write any code for table creation in onCreate().Please take care about SQLiteOpenHelper Class :-

1. onCreate() – These is where we need to write create table
   statements.    This is called when database is created.
2. onUpgrade() – This method is called when database is upgraded like
   modifying the table structure, adding constraints to database etc.,

   So in onCreate() you have to write logic for  create table.